# jQuery Mobile .live not working on form submit buttons

Tags: jquery, jquery-mobile

I'm trying to add a listener on all of the submit buttons in my dialogs.  Problem is, my `.live()` listeners aren't being executed and I can't figure out why.

If I use an onClick it'll work, but I'd rather be more efficient and not have to add onClick to all my submi buttons.

Any thoughts?

```
$('input[type="submit"]').live('click', (function (e) {
    alert('test'); //never executes
}));
```

I am loading my `base.js` file after jquery is loaded on the page.  It is not inside any kind of `$(document).ready();` or anything.

Answer (score 1):

If your goal is to be more efficient, then you should be avoiding the .live function as much as possible. The live can take a lot more event bubbling before it triggers.  Your on-page-performance would be much faster if you just used a named function and put it in the onclick event of your link, you'd have the best performance possible.  This also avoids the performance hit caused by closures.

The next fastest way you could do it would be to attach the events directly to the buttons on the pagecreate event like this.  It would prevent the closure issues and reduce event bubbling.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function mySubmitHandler(){
      alert("test");
    }

    $("div").live("pagecreate", function(){
        $('input[type="submit"]').bind('click', mySubmitHandler);
    });
</script>
```

Comment: Nice... thanks... how come using a named function is faster/more efficient?

Comment: From:
https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Guide/Closures

Performance considerations

It is unwise to unnecessarily create functions within other functions if closures are not needed for a particular task as it will negatively affect script performance both in terms of processing speed and memory consumption.

Comment: That's odd, seems silly.  I would think it requires more memory to give a function a name.....

Answer (score 0):

Could the [prevent default](http://api.jquery.com/event.preventDefault/) be the issue here?

See if [this](http://jsfiddle.net/Cngp2/) works.

Comment: Thanks, but I'm using jQuery mobile, the jsfiddle doesn't have that included.

Comment: No problem, though you can always take that code and test it with jQuery mobile, right?